# Separate Verbatim into two columns

Tags: verbatim

Is it possible to split a long verbatim simply into 2 columns? For example:

```
 \begin{verbatim}
 a
 a
 a
 b
 b
 \end{verbatim}
```

result displayed (b starting at the middle of the page):

```
a       b
a       b
a
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the package `multicol` that allows doing two columns text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{verbatim}
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
\end{verbatim}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]